# Multi-Threading in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I wrote this program, that is supposed to read about 5000 email address and send an pre-defined html mail. I am using the background worker component.

The problem is this: I have wired up the method who is supposed to send the mail. But I am calling another method that is supposed to append the body html to the salutation, like

```
public string GiveMeFullHtml(string personname)
 ... "Dear Mr. John Doe" + HTML ...
```

It seems that when it hits this method call, operation completes. IUt only sends the first mail and completes. I think because the HTML string method is on another thread or sth like that. Can you give me a little insight. Do I have to get everything done in the very same method when using multi-threading? Thanks in advance

### The full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WinSendMail
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable adrs = new DataTable("Addresses");
        string headerHtml = @"<div style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px; color: #333'><table style='width: 375pt; background-color: #e5eaf1;' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tbody><tr><td style='background: #e5eaf1;'>";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int totalAdresCount = 0;
        protected DataTable AdresleriAl()
        {
            using (DAL dal = new DAL())
            {
                DataTable dt = dal.GetTable("SELECT [ID],[Eposta],[Ad_Soyad] FROM [UYELER] WHERE [ID] IN (5923,5924,5875) ORDER BY [ID] ASC", false, null);
                   totalAdresCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                   labAdresAlindi.Text = totalAdresCount.ToString() + "addresses found";
                return dt;
            }
        }
        private void btnAdresAl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adrs = AdresleriAl();
            btnAdresAl.Text = totalAdresCount.ToString() + " members found";
            btnAdresAl.Enabled = false;
            foreach (DataRow r in adrs.Rows)
            {
                string line = r[1].ToString() + " ( " + r[2].ToString() + " : " + r[0].ToString() + " )";
                string email = r[1].ToString();

                RadListBoxItem item = new RadListBoxItem(line, email);
                radListBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SablonlariGetir();
        }
        //protected string OzellestirilmisSablonHTML(int id)
        //{
            //string adsoyad = String.Empty;
            //string tckimlik = String.Empty;
            //string basvuruno = String.Empty;
            //string eposta = String.Empty;
            //string sifre = String.Empty;

            //string sSql = "SELECT [Ad_Soyad],[TC_Kimlik_No],[Basvuru_No],[Eposta],[Sifre] from [UYELER] WHERE [ID]=" + id.ToString();
            //using (DAL dal = new DAL())
            //{
            //    string[] dudeData = dal.SelectRow(sSql, false, null);
            //    if (null == dudeData) return null;
            //    basvuruno = dudeData[2];
            //    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(basvuruno)) { return null; };
            //    adsoyad = dudeData[0];
            //    tckimlik = dudeData[1];
            //    eposta = dudeData[3];
            //    sifre = dudeData[4];
            //}
            /////Mesaj kişi kısmını oluştur
            /////
            //string ozelmesaj = "";
            //ozelmesaj = headerHtml;
            //ozelmesaj += "<img alt='' src='http://imageurl'><br/><br/>";
            //ozelmesaj += "<div style='padding: 10px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size:14px'>";
            //ozelmesaj += "Sayın <strong>" + adsoyad + @"</strong>,&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            //ozelmesaj += "<i>(T.C. Kimlik No: " + tckimlik + ")</i><br/><br/>";
            ////ozelmesaj += "Başvuru bilgilerinizi, üyelik test duyurusunu ve Başkanımız ın<br/>mesajını bilginize sunarız.";

            //ozelmesaj += "Başkanımız Alphan Manas'ın mesajını bilginize sunarız.";

            //ozelmesaj += "<hr/>";
            ////ozelmesaj += "<strong>Şifreniz: </strong>" + sifre + "<br/>";
            ////ozelmesaj += "<strong>Giriş Sayfası: </strong>" + "<a href='#' target='_new'>click here</a>" + "<br />";
            ////ozelmesaj += "<strong>Başvuru No: </strong>" + basvuruno + "<br/>";
            ////ozelmesaj += "<strong>E-posta Adresi: </strong>" + eposta + "<br/>";
            //ozelmesaj += "</div>";
            //ozelmesaj += "</td></tr>";

            //ozelmesaj = ozelmesaj + htmlEditor1.InnerHtml;

            //return ozelmesaj;
        //}
        protected void SablonlariGetir()
        {
            string sSql = "SELECT [ID],[Subject] FROM [Sablonlar] ORDER BY [ID] DESC";
            using (DAL dal = new DAL())
            {
                DataTable dt = dal.GetTable(sSql, false, null);
                if (dt == null) return;
                radComboBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    radComboBox1.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(row[1].ToString(), row[0].ToString()));
                }
                radComboBox1.SelectedIndex = radComboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }
        private void radComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radComboBox1.SelectedValue == null) return;
            slcSubjectText = radComboBox1.SelectedText;
            string sql = "SELECT [Subject],[Body] FROM [Sablonlar] WHERE [ID]=" + radComboBox1.SelectedValue;
            using (DAL dal = new DAL())
            {
                string htmlcode = dal.SelectRow(sql, false, null)[1];
                htmlEditor1.InnerHtml = htmlcode;
            }
        }
        protected void MailGonder(string to, string subject, string body)
        {
            //MailAddress adr1 = new MailAddress("webform@mensa-turkey.org","Mensa Türkiye");
            //MailAddress adr2 = new MailAddress(to,"");
            //MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(adr1,adr2);
            //msg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("info@mensa-turkey.org");
            //msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            //msg.Subject = subject;
            //msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            //msg.Body = body;
            //SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25);
            //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            //try
            //{
            //    client.Send(msg);
            //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            //}   
        }

        protected void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //string msg = count.ToString() + " mails sent";
            //MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }

        private void ToggleStuff(bool state)
        {
            htmlEditor1.ReadOnly = !state;
            radButton1.Enabled = state;
            button2.Enabled = state;
            radListBox1.Enabled = state;
            radComboBox1.Enabled = state;
        }

        protected void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            labProgres.Text = count.ToString() + " / " + totalAdresCount.ToString() + " posta gönderildi.";
        }

        int count = 0;
        string slcSubjectText = "Mensa Türkiye";

        void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtKisiler = e.Argument as DataTable;
            foreach (DataRow row in dtKisiler.Rows)
            {
                string to = row[1].ToString();
                string body = "";

                ////////////////////////
                string adsoyad = String.Empty;
                string tckimlik = String.Empty;
                string basvuruno = String.Empty;
                string eposta = String.Empty;
                string sifre = String.Empty;

                string sSql = "SELECT [Ad_Soyad],[TC_Kimlik_No],[Basvuru_No],[Eposta],[Sifre] from [UYELER] WHERE [ID]=" + id.ToString();
                using (DAL dal = new DAL())
                {
                    string[] dudeData = dal.SelectRow(sSql, false, null);
                    basvuruno = dudeData[2];
                    adsoyad = dudeData[0];
                    tckimlik = dudeData[1];
                    eposta = dudeData[3];
                    sifre = dudeData[4];
                }
                ///Mesaj kişi kısmını oluştur
                ///
                string ozelmesaj = "";
                ozelmesaj = headerHtml;
                ozelmesaj += "<img alt='' src='http://www.mensa-turkey.org/mail_banner.jpg'><br/><br/>";
                ozelmesaj += "<div style='padding: 10px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size:14px'>";
                ozelmesaj += "Sayın <strong>" + adsoyad + @"</strong>,&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                ozelmesaj += "<i>(T.C. Kimlik No: " + tckimlik + ")</i><br/><br/>";
                //ozelmesaj += "Başvuru bilgilerinizi, üyelik test duyurusunu ve Başkanımız Alphan Manas'ın<br/>mesajını bilginize sunarız.";

                ozelmesaj += "Başkanımız Alphan Manas'ın mesajını bilginize sunarız.";

                ozelmesaj += "<hr/>";
                //ozelmesaj += "<strong>Şifreniz: </strong>" + sifre + "<br/>";
                //ozelmesaj += "<strong>Giriş Sayfası: </strong>" + "<a href='http://www.mensa-turkey.org/index.asp?id=25' target='_new'>http://www.mensa-turkey.org/index.asp?id=25</a>" + "<br />";
                //ozelmesaj += "<strong>Başvuru No: </strong>" + basvuruno + "<br/>";
                //ozelmesaj += "<strong>E-posta Adresi: </strong>" + eposta + "<br/>";
                ozelmesaj += "</div>";
                ozelmesaj += "</td></tr>";

                ozelmesaj = ozelmesaj + htmlEditor1.InnerHtml;
                body = ozelmesaj;

                ////////////////////////
                if (body != null)
                {
                    htmlEditor1.InnerHtml = body;
                    try
                    {
                        MailAddress adr1 = new MailAddress("webform@mensa-turkey.org", "Mensa Türkiye");
                        MailAddress adr2 = new MailAddress(to, "");
                        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(adr1, adr2);
                        msg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("info@mensa-turkey.org");
                        msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                        msg.Subject = slcSubjectText;
                        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        msg.Body = body;
                        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("212.154.55.179", 25);
                        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("webform", "aaa-12345");
                        try
                        {
                            client.Send(msg);
                            count++;
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(count);
                        }
                        catch (Exception x)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radListBox1.Items.Count <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gönderecek kimse yok");
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(radComboBox1.SelectedText) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlEditor1.InnerHtml))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Başlık / Mesaj eksik");
                return;
            }
            ToggleStuff(false);
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(adrs);
        }

        private void btnCheckCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HTMLView view = new HTMLView();
            view.SetHtmlCode(htmlEditor1.InnerHtml);
            view.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You expect someone `guessing` the code you wrote and give you correction?

Comment: Yes, we need a code snippet in order to provide better answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, shall I paste it all :)

Comment: why on earth would you post commented out code?

Comment: How about just the RELEVANT code?

Comment: yeah, sorry, i am in a rush :( just made ctrl+A

Comment: I'm gonna use dudeData variable name in my next project :)

Answer (score 0):

Think about this way:

```
static readonly string mail = "{0} {1}";
static readonly string HTML = "...";
```

in you main method:

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);

bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new 
    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

in the bgWorker_DoWork run:

```
foreach (var userName in userlist)
{
   //send the mail using string.Format(mail, userName, HTML)
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. string.Format .. is that because static methods can be accesses by different threads? is there anything like that?

Comment: the static strings are because they are accessed by different threads, the string.Format is an easy&light way of combining the two (and if you'll have more than the two in the future) in the order you want without iteratively appending strings.
Has the answer helped you?

Comment: Yes the "Static" was the exact answer I was after, Thank you very very much :)

Comment: No problem, I'll appreciate it if you could accept it as your answer.
Good luck.